# Is there a name for this alternative binary representation

Tags: encoding, binary, binary-data, notation

### Question

In a project I am working on, I'm having to process the encodings for assembly language instructions.  Often, in this space, there is the need to represent all encodings but one.

I've created a notation for binary numbers that allows me to represent this in a compact form.

**Is there a name for this kind of notation?**

In my notation the following two encodings cover the entire 16-bit encoding space:

```
-------DDD------ // DDD represents 000/001/010/011/100/101/110 -- everything but 111
-------111------
```

Similarly, these two encodings would cover the entire 16-bit encoding space:

```
-------dDd------ // dDd represents 000/001/011/100/101/110/111 -- everything but 010
-------010------
```

If there's a name for this notation, I might be able to find algorithms that can manipulate these encodings and not have to create these algorithms from scratch (which is what I have been doing).

### Background

This notation can come in handy in representing instruction set encodings.

Given a 16-bit instruction set where an instruction might have the following format where the opcode is in [15:9], the destination register is in [8:6], source 1 is in [5:3] and source 2 is in [2:0]:

```
1
5     9 8 6 5 3 2 0
------- --- --- ---
0000000 Rd  S1   S2    ADD Rd = S1, S2
```

The designers of the instruction set might disallow Rd from being R7 (e.g. with an encoding 0b111) for ADD so that bits of, say, S2 might be used to encode more opcode space to represent single source instructions.

```
0000000 111 S1  000    NEG R7 = S1
```

In order to work with these instruction encodings, I've created a representation to indicate when an encoding or part of an encoding has all values except for a given value.

So the ADD and NEG instructions above might be represented as

```
0000000 DDD --- ---    ADD Rd = S1, S2
0000000 111 --- 000    NEG R7 = S1
```